# How to restrict edit option after submission of form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, designer-workflow, infopath-data-connections

I have created the form in custom list. Now I have below requirements:

- Once the user is submitted the form, He/she should not have an option to edit or delete items.
- Its an survey form, I want configure summary report for that list item also.

Comment: Any news to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach SPD workflow to remove the edit permission of user. Just keep read permission. This way user will not be able to edit the item.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create new custom permission level with only add and view rights.
2. Give access to users with this new permission level on that list
3. This way user will able to only add items but they will not able to edit it.

To know more about permission level you can refer below link: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/How-to-create-and-edit-Permission-Levels-53c86040-07fa-4ea7-bc55-34ee96b437fe

Answer (score 0):

Open your list in SharePoint Designer and create a SharePoint 2010 Workflow.

Then first add the Impersonation Step above the step which is already provided.

[image]

Then under Actions, select "Replace List Item Permissions".

[image]

Then replace the permissons as you want:

[image]

And do that for your "Current Item".

[image]

Hope this helps. Of course make sure that the workflow runs when you want it to do.

Comment: This worked awesome ... Thank so much :). How about getting survey summary report of this list ? Much appreciated if you could help me

Comment: You could e.G. in the step "Read Only WF" add an action "send E-Mail" where you can send a user or a group an info e-mail. Otherwise you can update the workflowstatus (which is not that "fancy" as an report)

Comment: But I asked i want a graphical summary report of all the responses that will log in this custom list  : Survey Name: Survey 
Survey Description:  
Time Created: 11/20/2015 11:31 AM 
Number of Responses: 1 
 

 
 Show a graphical summary of responses  
 Show all responses

Comment: Well, that's above my knowledge... you maybe could create an item in a new list when then workflow runs and create a view with chart.js...

Answer (score 0):

To create a graphical summary, you can export all the repsonses to the Excel and create a pivot chart

An example can be found here:

http://tavislovell.com/create-a-dashboard-from-your-sharepoint-list-data-using-excel-services-and-the-excel-web-access-web-part/